# How to get the position value with a Trinamic 5130 (Python+RPI) without stopping the motor?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, spi, stepper

I've got strange behavior with a Trinamic 5130 stepper motor driver.

The code runs on a raspberry pi using SPI. I use a Trinamic EVAL board.

When I run the code below, as expected, the motor goes to a position ([0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00]) then goes back in [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00].

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding = utf-8

import sys
import spidev

class motor():
    def __init__(self, spi_bus, chip_select):
        self.spi_bus = spi_bus
        self.spi_chip_select = chip_select
        self.spi_max_speed = 500000
        self.spi_mode = 0

        self.spi = spidev.SpiDev()
        # Open a connection to a specific bus and device (chip select pin)
        self.spi.open(self.spi_bus, self.spi_chip_select)
        # Set SPI speed and mode
        self.spi.max_speed_hz = self.spi_max_speed
        self.spi.mode = self.spi_mode

        self.register_addr = {  "GCONF": {"addr": 0x00, "access": "RW"}, # normal mode + stealth chop (stealthChop voltage PWM mode enabled (depending on velocity thresholds). Switch on while in stand still, only.)
                                "GSTAT": {"addr": 0x01, "access": "R"}, # Write reset at start up
                                "IFCNT": {"addr": 0x02, "access": "R"},
                                "SLAVECONF": {"addr": 0x03, "access": ""}, # not used in SPI mode
                                "IOIN": {"addr": 0x04, "access": "R"},
                                "X_COMPARE": {"addr": 0x05, "access": "RW"},
                                "IHOLD_IRUN": {"addr": 0x10, "access": "W"}, # Current control with stealthChop mode
                                "TPOWERDOWN": {"addr": 0x11, "access": "W"}, # (Reset default=20) Sets the delay time from stand still (stst) detection to motor current power down. Time range is about 0 to 5.6 seconds. 0...((2^8)-1) * 2^18 tclk Attention: A minimum setting of 2 is required to allow automatic tuning of stealthChop PWM_OFFS_AUTO.
                                "TSTEP": {"addr": 0x12, "access": "R"},
                                "TPWMTHRS": {"addr": 0x13, "access": "W"}, # unclear
                                "TCOOLTHRS": {"addr": 0x14, "access": "W"}, #This is the lower threshold velocity for switching on smart energy coolStep and stallGuard feature.
                                "THIGH": {"addr": 0x15, "access": "W"},
                                "RAMPMODE": {"addr": 0x20, "access": "W"}, # 0: Positioning mode (using all A, D and V parameters) 1: Velocity mode to positive VMAX (using AMAX acceleration)
                                "XACTUAL": {"addr": 0x21, "access": "RW"}, # Actual motor position (signed) Hint: This value normally should only be modified, when homing the drive. In positioning mode, modifying the register content will start a motion.
                                "VACTUAL": {"addr": 0x22, "access": "RW"}, # Actual motor velocity from ramp generator (signed) The sign matches the motion direction. A negative sign means motion to lower XACTUAL.
                                "VSTART": {"addr": 0x23, "access": "W"}, # Motor start velocity (unsigned) Set VSTOP = VSTART!
                                "A1": {"addr": 0x24, "access": "W"}, # First acceleration between VSTART and V1 (unsigned)
                                "V1": {"addr": 0x25, "access": "W"}, # First acceleration / deceleration phase threshold velocity (unsigned) 0: Disables A1 and D1 phase, use AMAX, DMAX only
                                "AMAX": {"addr": 0x26, "access": "W"}, # Second acceleration between V1 and VMAX (unsigned) This is the acceleration and deceleration value for velocity mode.
                                "VMAX": {"addr": 0x27, "access": "W"}, # Motion ramp target velocity (for positioning ensure VMAX = VSTART) (unsigned) This is the target velocity in velocity mode. It can be changed any time during a motion.
                                "DMAX": {"addr": 0x28, "access": "W"}, # Deceleration between VMAX and V1 (unsigned)
                                "D1": {"addr": 0x2A, "access": "W"}, # Deceleration between V1 and VSTOP (unsigned) Attention: Do not set 0 in positioning mode, even if V1=0!
                                "VSTOP": {"addr": 0x2B, "access": "W"}, # Motor stop velocity (unsigned) Attention: Set VSTOP = VSTART! Attention: Do not set 0 in positioning mode, minimum 10 recommend!
                                "TZEROWAIT": {"addr": 0x2C, "access": "W"}, # Defines the waiting time after ramping down to zero velocity before next movement or direction inversion can start. Time range is about 0 to 2 seconds. 
                                "XTARGET": {"addr": 0x2D, "access": "RW"}, # Target position for ramp mode (signed).
                                "VDCMIN": {"addr": 0x33, "access": "W"}, # Automatic commutation dcStep becomes enabled above velocity VDCMIN (unsigned)
                                "SWMODE": {"addr": 0x34, "access": "RW"}, # reference switch input
                                "RAMPSTAT": {"addr": 0x35, "access": "R"}, # Reference switch
                                "XLATCH": {"addr": 0x36, "access": "R"}, # programmable switch event
                                "ENCMODE": {"addr": 0x38, "access": "RW"}, # channel event
                                "XENC": {"addr": 0x39, "access": "RW"}, # Actual encoder position
                                "ENC_CONST": {"addr": 0x3A, "access": "W"}, # encoder
                                "ENC_STATUS": {"addr": 0x3B, "access": "R"}, # Encoder status
                                "ENC_LATCH": {"addr": 0x3C, "access": "R"}, # Encoder position X_ENC latched on N event
                                "MSLUT0":     {"addr": 0x60, "access":"W"}, # microstep table entry 0-31
                                "MSLUT1":     {"addr": 0x61, "access":"W"},
                                "MSLUT2":     {"addr": 0x62, "access":"W"},
                                "MSLUT3":     {"addr": 0x63, "access":"W"},
                                "MSLUT4":     {"addr": 0x64, "access":"W"},
                                "MSLUT5":     {"addr": 0x65, "access":"W"},
                                "MSLUT6":     {"addr": 0x66, "access":"W"},
                                "MSLUT7":     {"addr": 0x67, "access":"W"},
                                "MSLUTSEL":   {"addr": 0x68, "access":"W"}, # LUT width and segment start config
                                "MSLUTSTART": {"addr": 0x69, "access":"W"}, # Absolute current for microstep table entry
                                "MSCNT":      {"addr": 0x6A, "access":"R"}, # Microstep counter. Indicates actual position in the microstep table
                                "MSCURACT":   {"addr": 0x6B, "access":"R"}, # Actual microstep current for motor phase
                                "CHOPCONF":   {"addr": 0x6C, "access":"RW"}, # Chopper mode config
                                "COOLCONF":   {"addr": 0x6D, "access":"W"}, # stallGuard config
                                "DCCTRL":   {"addr": 0x6E, "access":"W"}, # PWM config
                                "DRVSTATUS":   {"addr": 0x6F, "access":"R"}, # Driver status
                                "PWMCONF":   {"addr": 0x70, "access":"W"}, # PMW config
                                "PWMSCALE":   {"addr": 0x71, "access":"R"}, # Actual PWM amplitude scaler (255=max. Voltage) In voltage mode PWM, this value allows to detect a motor stall.
                                "ENCM_CTRL":   {"addr": 0x72, "access":"W"}, 
                                "LOST_STEPS":   {"addr": 0x73, "access":"R"}, 
        }

    def connect(self):
        spi = spidev.SpiDev()
        # Open a connection to a specific bus and device (chip select pin)
        spi.open(self.spi_bus, self.spi_chip_select)

        # Set SPI speed and mode
        spi.max_speed_hz = self.spi_max_speed
        spi.mode = self.spi_mode

        return spi

    def address_resolver(self, addr):
        return self.register_addr[addr]["addr"]

    def register_access(self, addr, rw):
        """"Checking register access right"""
        if rw not in self.register_addr[addr]["access"]:
            print(f"Error {addr} Register can't be {rw}, system stop.")
            sys.exit(1)
        else:
            return 0

    def data_builder(self, addr, value, rw):
        """Build data trame.
        Check for register access, configure MSB and concate into a list.
        input:  register name, list of values, read of write status
        output: hexadecimal trame list [register_addr, val1, val2, val3, val4]"""
        addr_value = self.address_resolver(addr)
        self.register_access(addr, rw)

        # IF write to buffer => set MSB to 1
        if rw == "W":
            addr_value += 0x80 # set MSB to 1
        value.insert(0, addr_value)

        return value


    def send_data(self, data):
        "send data trame to driver using SPI"
        response = self.spi.xfer(data)
        return response


if __name__ == "__main__":

    motor_1 = motor(spi_bus=0, chip_select=0)

    # print("GSTAT R") 
    # data = [0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00] 0x01
    data = motor_1.data_builder("GSTAT", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "R")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # Initialize position
    data = motor_1.data_builder("XTARGET", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)
    data = motor_1.data_builder("XACTUAL", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # Write chopper configs 0x6C
    # data = [0xEC, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xC5]
    # print("CHOPCONF W") # EC
    data = motor_1.data_builder("CHOPCONF", [0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0xC5], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # Write IRUN=10 IHOLD=2 0x10
    # data = [0x90, 0x00, 0x06, 0x0A, 0x02]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("IHOLD_IRUN", [0x00, 0x06, 0x0A, 0x02], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # Write - Set RAMPMODE to 1 (Velocity mode) 0x20
    # data = [0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("RAMPMODE", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # A1 = 1, first acceleration 0x24
    # data = [0xA4, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xE8]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("A1", [0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0xE8], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # V1 = 50000 Acceleration threshold velocity 0x25
    # data = [0xA5, 0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x50]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("V1", [0x00, 0x00, 0xC3, 0x50], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # AMAX = 500 acceleration above V1 0x26
    # data = [0xA6, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF4]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("AMAX", [0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xF4], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # VMAX = 200000 0x27
    data = [0xA7, 0x00, 0x03, 0x0D, 0x40]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("VMAX", [0x00, 0x03, 0x0D, 0x40], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # DMAX = 700 deceleration above V1 0x28
    # data = [0xA8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xBC]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("DMAX", [0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0xBC], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # D1 = 1400 deceleration below V1 0x2A
    # data = [0xAA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x78]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("D1", [0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x78], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # VSTOP = 10 stop velocity (near to 0) 0x2B
    # data = [0xAB, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("VSTOP", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # RAMPMODE = 0 (Target position move) 0x20
    # data = [0xA0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
    data = motor_1.data_builder("RAMPMODE", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)

    # TEST Move
    import time

    data = motor_1.data_builder("XACTUAL", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "R")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)
    print(f"XACTUAL:{response}")

    data = motor_1.data_builder("XTARGET", [0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)
    print(f"Move to AA")

    time.sleep(2)
    data = motor_1.data_builder("XACTUAL", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "R")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)
    print(f"XACTUAL:{response}")

    data = motor_1.data_builder("XTARGET", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "W")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)
    print(f"Move to 00")

    time.sleep(2) # If small timing:0.1 => read XACTUAL during motor movement => stop the motor
    data = motor_1.data_builder("XACTUAL", [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00], "R")
    response = motor_1.send_data(data)
    print(f"XACTUAL:{response}")
```

Everything works fine, I got the position by reading the XACTUAL register.

I want to scan the motor position by reading the XACTUAL register as described in doc.

Problem:
If I read the XACTUAL register during the motor movement (time.sleep(0.1)), the motor stops and won't finish its run.

I really appreciate help.

Best,

Comment: Hi! Did you write this code yourself? I'm trying to connect 3 TMC5160s with a RasPi and I was looking for Python code to do that and your answer came up.

Comment: Hello Yiannis, I've write more drivers codes for 5160. I'll be glad to share it. Actually, I've upgrad the dev board (RasPi =>Jetson Orin Nano), only a SPI drivers install and no change on the code (even GPIO pins are the same). I think, you should start a new SO question like "how to drive a Trinamic 5160 with Python and RPi/linux SBC?".

Comment: Hi! I got it to work using your code and the Trinamic example on their website. I'm not sure how you got it working with what you posted here but it helped greately. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I’ve got the answer from MAXIM-TRINAMIC support (thanks a lot to Ahammad Fahad ).

This problem is due to an incompatible power supply.

The Raspberry Pi is powered by  5V and the TRINAMIC 5130-EVAL board by 3.3V.

Fix:
Re-solder one capacitor (C1) on the TMC5130-EVAL. This sets the logic level of the TMC5130 to +5V. While by default the capacitor is soldered to the “right-hand” position, you have to move it to the “left-hand” position for 5V operation.”

Note: I’ve corrected the TRINAMIC fix by replacing the resistor by capacitor in the text (measured: R=inf, C=0.6µF).

Same fix for apply to Arduino boards powered by 5V.

[image: TRINAMIC EVAL-BOARD FIX FOR 5V]
Picture from MAXIM-TRINAMIC.

I suppose the low voltage was fine for slow commands but when I’ve stressed the drivers, the system drops down.

Everthing works well.

I hope this help